# use output of python code block from other python code block

Tags: org-mode, python

My emacs is 29.2 in linux. I try below code to use output from first python block, but the output in second block is None after press C- C-c.

```
#+name: testblock
#+begin_src python
print("hello")
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :var x=testblock :results ouput 
print(x)
#+end_src
```

I would expect it output `Hello`

Comment: Evaluate the first block by pressing `C-c C-c` on it. What do you get? Does that help explain what you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `:results` header is `value`. So, org gets the value by wrapping the code in a function definition in the language of the source block. Code should execute like a function and return a value.

In the first block, you are not returning anything and so its value is taken as `None` and fed to the second block.

I suggest you to change your code as below,

```
#+name: testblock 
#+begin_src python :results output
print( "hello" )
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :var x=testblock :results output 
print(x)
#+end_src
```

or alternatively, you can remove the `results` header & just use `return` instead of `print`.

Comment: "The default `:results` header is `value`" - yes, for Python (and most other languages); but not for *every* language - e.g. for `shell` the default is `output`. It is safest to explicitily specify what you want in all cases.